# Joomla page redirection

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, joomla3.0

In my URL the page is showing like `www.domainname.com/index.php/events/?txtlabel=tender`
Now if user is typing `www.domainname.com/tender`, the URL would be redirected to the above URL.

But for other pages, the URL would be same as it is, like `www.domainname.com/index.php/XXXX`.
I have tried using the index.php file. But it is not possible in this page.

Where would I write this exception so that without hampering the whole site, only this page would work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JoomSEF component for url redirection in Joomla.

http://www.artio.net/downloads/joomla/joomsef